# What should Id method do in Asp.net EF Migration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core

I've generated a file using `dnx ef migration add CreateUserTable` however unlike all the examples I find online my file is extending `Migration` instead of `DbMigration` and it is complaining that I need to implement `public override string Id`

The auto implementation of Visual studios just has a get method with an exception being thrown.

**Question**

What am I suppose to do with this and can anyone point me to some documentation?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Can you share your code sample and the examples you are referring to?

Comment: Well it seems like it was related to being beta software. I've re-installed all the things after rc-update1 and everything is working correctly. In previous beta release it was requiring me to override the Id which it no longer does so I cannot paste a code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade to rc-update1. It appears to be buggy in the beta version.